# BoxLayout design

Tags: python, kivy

This is my code:

```
layout = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')
    layout2 = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')

    button1 = Button()
    button2 = Button()
    button3 = Button()
    button4 = Button()
    button5 = Button()
    button6 = Button()


    layout.add_widget(button1)
    layout.add_widget(button2)
    layout.add_widget(button3)
    layout2.add_widget(button4)
    layout2.add_widget(button5)
    layout2.add_widget(button6)

    layout.add_widget(layout2)

    return layout
```

And this is the output i get.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ei9br.png

How can i move the small boxes from the right side to the left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its about the order you add the widgets.

Change it to

```
layout = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')
layout2 = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')

button1 = Button()
button2 = Button()
button3 = Button()
button4 = Button()
button5 = Button()
button6 = Button()

layout2.add_widget(button4)
layout2.add_widget(button5)
layout2.add_widget(button6)

layout.add_widget(layout2)

layout.add_widget(button1)
layout.add_widget(button2)
layout.add_widget(button3)
```